# How to determine if an Azure Blob is an Append or Block Blob using C#

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I'm using the C# to attempt to use an Azure Blob file (download, existence check, get properties etc).

I have no control over the creation of the Blob file (it could be a Block or an Append blob). Before I can do anything with the blob file I need to understand its type so I can get a reference to it.

Is there a way to do this, I couldn't see any file properties that shouted out

- "I'm an **append** blob"
- "I'm a **block** blob"

My Code looks similar to this:

```
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
```

However, since I won't know the blob type I need to determine it and if necessary execute the following method instead:

```
var blob = container.GetAppendBlobReference(blobName);
```

What have I looked for:

- Tried to find info on the Microsoft website

  - most seems to be about creating blobs, not consuming them, or the examples know what type to expect.
- There is a stackoverflow answer ([How to determine the Blob type of all the blobs in a container in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517290/how-to-determine-the-blob-type-of-all-the-blobs-in-a-container-in-azure)) for the Java scenario but I don't see a method called GetClass() on the Microsoft Nuget package library C# classes (maybe I should be using a different library)

```
if (CloudBlockBlob.class == blobItem.getClass()) {
    blob = (CloudBlockBlob)blobItem;
}
else if (CloudPageBlob.class == blobItem.getClass()) {
    blob = (CloudPageBlob)blobItem;
}
else if (CloudAppendBlob.class == blobItem.getClass()) {
    blob = (CloudAppendBlob)blobItem;
}
```

- Maybe there is an attribute or property/metadata that I can retrieve? I've looked but can't see anything obvious.

Any thoughts or guidance much appreciated thank you.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the way to get blob type by Azure storage C# sdk, just try the simple console app code below:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System;

namespace BlobTypeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var conn_str = "<your storage account connextion string>";
            var storageAccountName = "<your storage account name>";
            var containerName = "<container name>";
            var blobName = "<blob name>";

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount  = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(conn_str);

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var blobURI = "https://" + storageAccountName + ".blob.core.windows.net/" + containerName + "/" + blobName;

            var blob = blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(new Uri(blobURI));

            Console.WriteLine(blob.GetType());

        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

[image]

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much Stanley. Obvious when you know how! I'd looked through the FileProperties and not found anything. I really appreciate the brief console app too, very easy to test quickly.

Comment: @SJB,wlecome, glad to konw it is helpful